# VBA if cell value is not current date, input text on other cell

Tags: vba, date, input

I have an excel sheet in which I order tasks by date. What I want to do is when one tasks is overdue, (date is not current date), to input an "!" sign on other cell in the same row.

**For example:**

The column on which I have the dates is column D from D4 to D11.

The column on which I need the exclamation mark to be shown is column H from H4 to H11.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. The loop will continue until it reach an empty cell. You can adapt it if it didn't suit you.

`

```
Sub overdue_date()

Dim today As Date
Dim i As Integer

i = 4
today = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    While (Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 4)))
        If (.Cells(i, 4) < today) Then
            .Cells(i, 8) = "!"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End With
End Sub`
```

You may have to change the format of the date.